# Recommended Languages to Learn Linux

Tags: command-line, programming

This is a very common question i might be asking, but I have not come through a clear cut answer yet.
I want to be a fully Linux Developer, (BOTH Backend/Coder and GUI). 
Which programming Languages should I learn?

(Currently I am learning Shell Scripting).

Thank you. :)

Comment: That is indeed a very (too) broad question in my opinion. Apart from the fact that any advice would be subjective. It highly depends on the purpose *and* your personal preference.

Comment: "Which programming Languages should I learn?" No context. so all of them is the only correct answer here.   A *programmer* picks the language a certain task needs and does not limit himself. A "coder" jumps into a language and sticks with that.

Comment: What coding experience do you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my limited knowledge I can recommend both Python and C. As you may know there isn't a 'the best' language.
You can see lots of discussion on the topic like the one in [here](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/08/12/06/2044216/what-programming-language-for-linux-development) or [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4402) or [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1940339)  or [this one](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/236614-50-most-linux-related-programming-language) that might also be help to you.